# Update-query on ms access using data from another query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm building a database to be used in a hospital. In the "PatientsT" table, I have a field named "visits" set as a number, aimed to list the amount of times the patient has visited the hospital. Now, I have another table named "VisitsT" which lists all visits by all patients. 
I built a simple query Q1 which lists how many times each patient visited the hospital, result example:

patientID //// Visits

000001    /////////         2

000002        /////////     3

What I want to do is use the data from the above query, and with the help of an Update Query, add the numbers from Q1 to the appropriate place in the table PatientsT.

I was told this can be done without SQL - all leads appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do this by using an update query 
[image]

Edit: please put `[Q1].[Visits]` in the `Update to:` box instead

Comment: Did you mean to put that in the the "Update To" box?